# C++ noexcept unknown member function

Tags: c++, expression, noexcept

```
#include<iostream>
#include<utility>
using namespace std;

struct A
{
    void set(const int &){}
    void set(int &&) noexcept
    {}
};

template<class Assign,class T,class Func>
struct B
{
    B& operator=(const Assign &)
    {
        return *this;
    }
    B& operator=(Assign &&) noexcept(noexcept(declval<T>().set(declval<Assign>())))
    {
        return *this;
    }
};

int main()
{
    cout<<is_nothrow_assignable<B<int,A,void(A::*)(int &&)>&,int&&>::value<<endl;
}
```

I want to make the line

```
B& operator=(Assign &&) noexcept(noexcept(declval<T>().set(declval<Assign>())))
```

to

```
B& operator=(Assign &&) noexcept(noexcept(declval<T>().Func(declval<Assign>())))
```

(But it occurs compilation error.)
So that user can specify which member function should be used.
Is there *any possible* to do that without knowing which member function should be called in advance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use another parameter to specify the function, it'll work.

```
template<class Assign,class T,class Func, Func f> struct B
//...
B& operator=(Assign &&) noexcept(noexcept((declval<T>().*f)(declval<Assign>())))
//...
cout<<is_nothrow_assignable<B<int,A,void(A::*)(int &&), &A::set>&,int&&>::value<<endl;
```

Add a `Func` non-type parameter to `B`, use member function pointer call syntax in the `noexcept` operator, and then you can specify the function by passing a pointer to it.

Full code [here,](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2d5371fbbffb1af9) if it needs more context.

Comment: Although this is not what I want, it seems like this is only way to do that.